# How to reference array in an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make an array like the one below:

```php
$database = array(
    array(
        "key" => "Key1",
        "hwid" => "Hwid1"
    ),
    array(
        "key" => "Key2",
        "hwid" => "Hwid2"
    ),
);
```

How would I go about making this by inserting values. Here is what I have tried:

```php
$array = array();
$array[array()["key"]] = "Key1";
$array[array()["hwid"]] = "HWID1";
```

Sadly the above code does not make the structure of the array that I wanted. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = [];
$array[] = ["key" => "Key1","hwid" => "Hwid1"];
$array[] = ["key" => "Key2","hwid" => "Hwid2"];
```

or

```
$array = [
    ["key" => "Key1","hwid" => "Hwid1"],
    ["key" => "Key2","hwid" => "Hwid2"]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
$arr1 = ["id" => "id1", "hwid" => "hwid1"];
$arr2 = ["id" => "id2", "hwid" => "hwid2"];
array_push($array, $arr1, $arr2);
var_dump($array);
```

You don't need array index to be an array

Answer (score 0):

Your parent array is not associative, the only way you can access to it is by int index which starts with 0:

try this:

```
$array = array();
$array[0]["key"] = "Key1";
$array[0]["hwid"] = "HWID1";
```